# Objective C version of the unix "finger" command

Tags: objective-c, authentication, unix

I'm trying to check the time since last login in my Cocoa app. I would like to do it without having to do something like this:

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/finger"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObject: NSUserName()];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"%@", stringData);
```

For example, the Unix `whoami` command has the `NSUserName` Objective C equivalent.

Comment: It's not really a solution to your problem, but I will note that finger has about the simplest network protocol in the world.  Telnet to port 79, type your login name, and press return.  So you can avoid forking, at least.  (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1288)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a really interesting question! Thanks for asking. :)

As for the answer, I went and found the source to [`finger`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-138.1/finger/) and with it came up with the following:

```
#import <utmpx.h>

struct utmpx *user;
setutxent();
while ((user = getutxent()) != NULL) {
    if (user->ut_type == USER_PROCESS) {
        time_t loggedIn = user->ut_tv.tv_sec;
        NSDate * d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:loggedIn];
        NSLog(@"%s logged in at %@", user->ut_user, d);
    }
}
endutxent();
```

On my computer, this logs:

```
dave logged in at 2010-12-06 09:59:13 -0800
dave logged in at 2010-12-13 19:14:20 -0800
```

This matches the output of `finger dave` in Terminal:

```
Login: dave                     Name: Dave DeLong
Directory: /Users/dave                  Shell: /bin/bash
On since Mon Dec  6 09:59 (PST) on console, idle 7 days 9:18 (messages off)
On since Mon Dec 13 19:14 (PST) on ttys000
On since Thu Dec  9 17:21 (PST) on ttys001 (messages off)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to read in that info from the system files where that's stored. Maybe a 'utmp' file on unix.

After all, that's what 'finger' does.